# Merging two H20 dataframes Error: DistributedException 'Operation not allowed on string vector.'

Tags: python, dataframe, h2o

I am trying to merge two data frames after an operation.

```
import pandas as pd
import h2o
from h2o.automl import H2OAutoML
h2o.init()
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np



support = "splvl.csv"
data = h2o.import_file(support)

df1 = data[data['X'] == 0]
df2 = data[data['X'] == 1]

df1.impute("A", method = "mean", by = ["B", "C"])
df1.impute("Q", method = "mode", by = ["B", "C"])

df2.impute("A", method = "mean", by = ["B", "C"])
df2.impute("Q", method = "mode", by = ["B", "C"])

df1["X"].table()
df2["X"].table()

df3 = df2.merge(df1)

h2o.export_file(df3, path = "merged.csv", force=True, parts=1)
```

I get the following error when I execute the export to CSV command,

> H2OServerError: HTTP 500 Server Error:
>   Server error water.util.DistributedException:
>     Error: DistributedException from /127.0.0.1:54321: 'Operation not allowed on string vector.'
>     Request: None

```
df3["X"].table()
```

> Server error water.exceptions.H2OKeyNotFoundArgumentException:
>     Error: Object 'py_13_sid_95bb' not found for argument: key
>     Request: GET /3/Frames/py_13_sid_95bb
>       params: {'row_count': '10', 'row_offset': '0', 'column_count': '-1', 'full_column_count': '-1', 'column_offset': '0'}

this error when i try to print value count in merged data frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue is likely that your `"X"` is of type string, you can do a check by running `df1["X"].types`. You can convert this to a factor column, which will then allow you to use `table()` by doing `df1["X"]=df1["X"].asfactor()`.

The reason you are seeing the second error is probably because `d3` failed to be created when you ran `df3 = df2.merge(df1)`.

I would recommend verifying your column data types, fixing those that need to be converted to factors and then trying the merge again.

Comment: thanks, `df1 = data[data['L2Support'] == '0'].asfactor()
df2 = data[data['L2Support'] == '1'].asfactor()

df1["L2Support"].types
df2["L2Support"].types` the type is enum now. But merging just leaves an empty dataframe. both df1 and df2 have the right data in them. `This H2OFrame is empty.
` when i print `df3` after `df3 = df1.merge(df2)`